# Теория. Как программа управляет другой программой

Tags: сервер, сеть, клиент-сервер, клиент

Меня интересует теоретический вопрос. Теоретический потому, что я вообще без понятия, как он может решаться. Если, например, есть программа, которая создаёт переменную А и присваивает её значение 1, то может ли существовать другая программа, которая каким-то образом получает доступ к переменным в первой программе, получает A, выводит его на экран, а затем меняет значение A на 0? Я предполагаю, что это возможно, и если да, то каким образом это делается?

Я не нашёл никакой информации по поводу своего вопроса. Я нашёл о том, что можно имитировать ввод, но я не хочу имитировать ввод, а хочу, чтобы одна программа управляла другой, как если бы это были сервер и клиент, при условии, что у меня уже есть клиент, и это какая-то сторонняя программа, которая сама по себе не подразумевает такого взаимодействия.

Comment: Чтобы программы взаимодействовали друг с другом, то они как минимум **должны** подразумевать такое взаимодействие. Есть определенные механизмы при помощи которых можно его организовать.

Comment: Примеры таких механизмов можно глянуть [здесь](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B5)